# Is there an Unsigned Integer in JSON Schema

Tags: jsonschema

I just created my JSON Schema and I can't find if there is some kind of unsigned integer.

Is there an unsigned integer type available in JSON Schema?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there isn't. Check [the 'type' section](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.6.25) for details. But you can do

```
{
   "type" : "integer",
   "minimum" : 0
}
```

Comment: I tried this solution but it did not work for me. The value "-1" is still accepted by JSON validator. Is there something else to do?

Comment: This can be a bug in the validator you use @Matthieu.V

Comment: Ok, I found out the cause. It is not really a bug, but the library I was using supported only draft v3 while this keyword is something like draft v4+.